# Secure ways to impersonate a user on UNIX

Tags: apache, unix, kerberos, impersonation, setuid

I have a web application running on Apache httpd server and on UNIX. Currently it uses Perl CGI-bin executable owned by root user and with 'setuid' bit set.  This root/setuid is set to run a command on behalf of remote-user of UI. Are there any alternatives to get impersonation in secure ways? or is it possible to get kerberos based impersonation for the application on UNIX based server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to examine [`ksu`](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/user/user_commands/ksu.html).